# Initialize nontrivial class members when created by PyObject_NEW

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment, allocation, cpython

I have a Python object referring to a C++ object.

Header:

```cpp
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <structmember.h>

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    FrameBuffer frame_buffer;
} PyFrameBuffer;

extern PyTypeObject PyFrameBuffer_type;

extern PyObject* PyFrameBuffer_NEW(size_t width, size_t height);
```

The C++ `FrameBuffer` class is following:

```cpp
class FrameBuffer {
public:
    explicit FrameBuffer(const size_t width, const size_t height);

    // ...

private:
    size_t m_width;
    size_t m_height;
    std::vector<Pixel> m_pixels;
};
```

`Pixel` is a simple class of few plain type elements.

The `PyFrameBuffer_NEW()` function is following:

```cpp
PyObject* PyFrameBuffer_NEW(size_t width, size_t height)
{
    auto* fb = (PyFrameBuffer*) PyObject_NEW(PyFrameBuffer, &PyFrameBuffer_type);

    if (fb != nullptr)
    {
        fb->frame_buffer = FrameBuffer(width, height);
    }

    return (PyObject*) fb;
}
```

This code crashs:

`fb->frame_buffer` is allocated with undefined values (`fb->frame_buffer.m_pixels.size()` is undefined).

During `fb->frame_buffer` assignment, there is a deallocation of an undefinied number of `Pixel` in `m_pixels`.

And so, it crash.

This code seems to *works*:

```cpp
/// ...
    if (fb != nullptr)
    {
        FrameBuffer fb_tmp(width, height);
        std::memcpy(&fb->frame_buffer, &fb_tmp, sizeof(FrameBuffer));
    }
// ...
```

But I suspect this is not the proper way to solve this issue (I suspect `Pixel`s in `fb_tmp` are desallocated outside the scope.

- What would the the proper way to solve this problem?
- Is there a commonly known approach on how to expose complex object in CPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used code similar to

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    FrameBuffer *frame_buffer;
} PyFrameBuffer;
```

and then

```
if (fb != nullptr)
{
    fb->frame_buffer = new FrameBuffer( ... );
}
```

But you have to account for deleting the object explicitly.  You'll need to add a [`tp_dealloc()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dealloc) to your `PyFrameBuffer` initialization that deletes the C++  `FrameBuffer` object:

```
delete fb->frame_buffer;
```

Also:

When you use C++ to create a Python extension module, you're linking in your code's C++ runtime libraries.  If more than one module uses C++, they **all** have to use the exact same C++ runtime libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wanted to avoid the use of a pointer but it doesn't seems to be possible.